# CreadtedDate not recognized

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, visualforce-component

The Opportunity CreatedDate is not recognized

```
for(Opportunity opp:[SELECT id,CloseDate,Name,FORMAT(amount), CurrencyIsoCode, StageName,Stage_C_Duration__c,CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId =: UserId and CloseDate < TODAY and IsClosed = False ORDER BY CloseDate ]) 
{
    createdt = Date.valueof(opp.CreatedDate); // ERROR LINE
    Age = currentdt.daysBetween(createdt);
    ClsPast.add(new Opportunity(opp.id,opp.Name,opp.StageName,opp.CloseDate,Age));  
}
return ClsPast;
```

Error Message:

> Variable does not exist: createdt.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Please [edit] your post to make it more clear.

Comment: yup. It says "Variable does not exist: CreatedDate". I'm getting this error at the line createdt = Date.valueof(opp.CreatedDate);**

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your post to include more of the preceding context.

Comment: Have you defined `createddt` previously as `Date createddt;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the createddt variable as Date.

> Date createddt = Date.valueof(opp.CreatedDate);

### Analysis:

The issue is not with `CreatedDate` since it is a Standard Opportunity field.

Possible mistakes can be:

**Using the value without querying:**

- Clearly in this case the field CreatedDate is present in the SOQL so that shouldn't be the issue.
- The exception would be different as `Field not queried thru SOQL`

**Invalid Sobject Field Name:**

- I tried simulating a case with misspelled field name and if thats the case the error would look something like this
- `Invalid field CreatedDates for SObject Opportunity`

**Variable not defined:**

- So the only possible thing going wrong is the variable `createddt` not being defined.
- `Variable does not exist: createddt`, this is the exact error I got while running in anonymous window

Try this:

```
for(Opportunity opp:[SELECT id,CloseDate,Name,FORMAT(amount), CurrencyIsoCode, StageName,Stage_C_Duration__c,CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId =: UserId and CloseDate < TODAY and IsClosed = False ORDER BY CloseDate ]) 
       {
         Date createdt = Date.valueof(opp.CreatedDate);
        Age = currentdt.daysBetween(createdt);
        ClsPast.add(new Opportunity(opp.id,opp.Name,opp.StageName,opp.CloseDate,Age));  
       }
        return ClsPast;
```

Comment: In the beginning defined the data type for Createdt.